# Certificate being rejected by Apple

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, onesignal

While configuring certificate for Push Notification on my ios build of cordova project using OneSignal, the certificate is getting rejected every time I'm trying to configure it.
I've followed steps mentioned in https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/generate-an-ios-push-certificate
[image]

I've tried using OneSignal Provisionator Tool, and generated certificate using KeyChain access as well without any result.

Comment: Same issue here, tested the connection to APNS using the certificate and I successfully received the message, must be some kind of bug with OneSignal. I've contacted their supprt.

Comment: any update so far @Rick ?

Comment: I've just tried again and it still doesn't work, no reply from support either.

Comment: okay. let me know once you get any update. I do update if I make it working.

Comment: Sure will do, thanks

Comment: I have the same issue

Comment: same issue here. It's been 3 days. I've tried both generating the certificate by myself and using OneSignal provisioning tool, but either way I keep getting the same error

Comment: Same issue. Uploading my cert manually to OneSignal and I know I followed the steps correctly, I've done this a bunch of times.

Comment: Just got a message back from support, it's fixed

Comment: Hey Guys, it was the issue with OneSingal's end. I've reached out to their support and seems they've fixed the issue. I've used provisionator tool to generate .p12 file and it got accepted. I hope that would work for manual way as well.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can test APNS connection with this script:

https://gist.github.com/greencoder/16d1f8d7b0fed5b49cf64312ce2b72cc

This script requires your key and certificate in pem format. To convert from p12 use

```
openssl pkcs12 -in PushCertKey.p12 -out PushCertKeyNoCrypt.pem -nodes
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I contacted the support and here is a troubleshoot for future reference:

1.With your newest certificate, try renaming it to something different than previous certificates and then uploading it again.

2.Also, some users have reported that their security software blocks this from uploading, please make sure that is not the case.

3.Please make sure you are uploading a .p12 Push Certificate and not a Distribution Certificate or anything else besides a .p12 Push Certificate.
Just click the "Choose File..." button if this is your first time uploading like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAtgw.jpg
Or the "I'd like to replace my production .p12 certificate" check box if you are replacing the certificate like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4brz.jpg

4.You can generate one with OneSignal provisionator tool or if you have been and it is not working, you will need to try to generate one manually.
You can follow this [Generate iOS certificate doc](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/generate-an-ios-push-certificate) step by step to generate certificate, I followed it and uploaded it successfully.

If it is still not working, you can contact them providing the p12 cert to them with password and OneSignal AppID. they may upload it for you as soon as they can.

Comment: I have checked all of those. Still getting rejected :/

Answer (score 0):

OneSignal had a service issue that caused certificates to be incorrectly detected as invalid. [It is now fixed, as noted in this status update](https://twitter.com/OneSignalStatus/status/904752067159384064).