# Onesignal - Production Certificate Rejected

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, onesignal

I'm trying to set up iOS push notifications via OneSignal for a second app on my developer account, but all of a sudden I'm getting this error:

"Your production certificate was rejected by Apple. It may be expired, revoked, or invalid. Double-check your file or use our provisionator tool to auto-generate a valid certificate."

Image: [OneSignal Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LISbM.png)

What's strange is I didn't have this problem at all for my first app, but now it's giving me this error. I've followed the documentation at https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/generate-an-ios-push-certificate and the claim from [Certificate being rejected by Apple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46012884/certificate-being-rejected-by-apple) that the issue has been resolved on Onesignal's side doesn't seem to hold true. I've also tried deleting all expired/revoked certificates in the keychain but the error persists. Could this be an issue with different certificates for multiple different apps?

Answer (score 0):

Just stumbled across the same issue today.

Solved by generating a new APN cert with a different CSR, download the APN cert and install to keychain, export the .p12 and upload to OneSignal.